# Excel Macro pause, resume, or end based on clicking of OK and Cancel in a input box

Tags: excel, vba

I am building a data validation between two databases workbook and need the macro to pause when a data mismatch is detected.  Id like to make the macro pause when the mismatch is detected and pop up a dialog box with an "OK" button and a "cancel" button.  I can't figure out how to make the macro resume when i press okay and stop when i press cancel.  Can anyone help?  btw im fairly new at VBA :)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please note that: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results." - help page for on topic questions. Please post what you have tried so far, including code, so we can see what you have and diagnose what you should add to it :) also, when the macro pauses, what are you doing to fix the mismatch? will you be changing the sheet data before resuming? will you be just looking at the data and resuming without chaning anything?

Comment: also what version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Thanks and from now on i will be more specific.  I just want the macro to stop to see if the mismatches were due to rounding (databases round differently) and if they are then continue the test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If MsgBox("Your message here", vbOkCancel) = vbCancel Then Exit Sub
```

Comment: Thanks that did it!!  Like i said i am new to this.  Appreciate the help